# Hide Div but show it as it slides up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I got my tabs working how I want - please view the site here: 
http://beelinetest.site50.net/uw_virtual_tour.html#

Does anyone know how I can hide the content at the bottom of the screen (scroll down), this is the info that slides up when the tab is clicked. But make sure it appears as it slides from behind the footer?

Comment: I looks like it slides up behind the foot now.  Please me as descriptive as possible when asking questions.

Comment: I see another issue if I fast click multiple tabs. Make sure to use `.stop(1)` before your `.animate(`

Comment: I wondered how to fix that, thanks roko-cant get it to quite work, do it put it before all .animatE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, add `overflow: hidden` to your `#maincontentcontainer` element.